# Using graph editor to manipulate movement speed but static rotation speed

Tags: animation, graph-editor

First of all, pardon me if the title is a little bit confusing. What I'm trying to make is a tossed coin animation. Like how a tossed coin should be, it move upward and rotating, and after reaching a certain height, it will slow down and finally fell (while still rotating).

Using graph editor I manage to manipulate the movement speed, but the problem is, I realized when the coin's movement started slowing down, so does the rotation speed. I wanted the rotation speed to be static in the whole animation.

Is there a way when I manipulate the animation in graph editor, it only affect the location but not the rotation?

Comment: if you unfold the tracks on the left, you'll see 3 different sort of tracks: location, rotation and scale, each for X, Y and Z, is it not what you're looking for?

Comment: I clicked on "Z Location" and resized the graph, but somehow I feel like the rotation also got affected even though I didn't select the "X Euler Rotation". I also tried to click the padlock icon next to the "X Euler Rotation" but it didn't helped